# How to render a list of drawables, side by side, in a view in Android

Tags: android, user-interface

I would like to render a list of drawables, side by side in a horizontal fashion, in a view in Android. I know a View has setCompoundDrawables, but that only allows me to add drawables to the left and to the right of a view. Is this the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own customized view with Linearlayout (for a short list) or RecyclerView (for a long list).
For better answers, let figure out more what you want to implement!